# Apache JMeter -How do I get variable value in __javaScript function

Tags: javascript, jmeter

How do I get variable value in __javaScript function ?

My code:

```
String[] zoollevelParams = Parameters.split(",");
Random random = new Random();
int zoomValue= Integer.parseInt(zoollevelParams[random.nextInt(10)]);
double lat = 50.669;
double lng = 5.499;
int numTiles = ${__javaScript(Math.pow(2\, "${zoomValue}"))};
```

This code is unbale to get value of **zoomValue** in __javaScript function call, how do I get value in this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't combine Java and Javascript code and don't need to.

Just keep using Java and take parameter from JMeter variables object `vars`:

```
 int numTiles = Math.pow(2, vars.get( "zoomValue"));
```

- Note: If you save zoomValue as Double or not a regular String use `vars.getObject`

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried your solution but I got an exception - org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String[] zoollevelParams = Parameters.split(","); Random random = new Random();  . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Static method pow( int, null ) not found in class'java.lang.Math'

Comment: It means `zoomValue` has no value. If you want more help share you test plan how zoomValue is defined

Answer (score 0):

**Don't inline JMeter Variables or Functions into scripts**, particular in your case __javaScript function is being executed **before** `zoomValue` is getting initialized.

1. Make sure you use the relevant [JSR223 Test Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
2. Make sure you select `groovy` from the "Language" dropdown
3. Make sure you have `Cache compiled script if available` box **ticked**
4. Amend the last line of your code to look like:

   ```
   int numTiles = Math.pow(2, zoomValue)
   ```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Math Pow Groovy]

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details on using Groovy for scripting in JMeter tests.